What is this site for? Can I ask translations here?
I often have some Chinese sentences wanted to be translated precisely. Could I ask here?
Thanks guys.

From our FAQ:

This site is about discussing about the finer points of the language,
  but also about less expert questions that might be encountered both
  when learning the language itself or when you're just interested in
  how it works.

You can ask specific questions regarding a translation if it requires expert translation that can't be taken from a regular Chinese dictionary or from another common source such as Google translate.
Asking for a straight forward sentence to be translated where no effort has been made to translate the sentence is off-topic and shouldn't be asked as this site is a learning resource and not a translation service.

We also have a specific section for translations:

Can I request a translation?
We do not forbid translation requests but note that this is not a translation service, so we will close any translation request that does not show research effort. Make sure you clearly show it in your question.

Or from the specific FAQ:

Translation: From any language to Chinese as long as: (1) you provide research effort, without it your question will be closed. (2) you provide a detailed explanation of the original expression word. From Chinese to other languages, please refer to the target language site.

